# what does server= means in ldap query

Tags: active-directory, ldap, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010, ldap-query

I am parsing Exchange 2010 Admin Events (they are written to event viewer).
I need to verify via LDAP query that the parameters received are valid (this is some sort of validation i guess, its legacy code).

The ldap query contains subquery: "server=SOME_IPV6_ADDRESS"

I failed to find documentation regarding to **server** attribute, I was looking at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675090(v=vs.85).aspx

At first, I thought the query fails due to fact that IPv6 is not supported, Now I see that **server** attribute is a mystery.

the complete ldap query syntax is:

```
(legacyexchangedn=*)(msexchrecipienttypedetails=*)(server=SOME_IPV6_I_DUNNO)(|(anr==someuser)(distinguishedname=someuser)(objectguid=someuser)(msexchimmutableid=someuser)(msexchimmutableid=someuser)(proxyAddresses=smtp:someuser)(userprincipalname=someuser)(msexchmailboxguid=someuser))
```

If I remove the (server=SOME_IPV6_I_DUNNO) part, the query works fine.
So what is the server=* used to ? maybe special exchange server attribute ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging all over, i found there is a class called server.
Description is located here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683948(v=vs.85).aspx